# How to make a certain div visible while hovering an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="parent.child">
      <a href="#"></a>
      <div class="parent.chil.child">
          <div class="parent.chil.child.child">
               <img src ="link0" >
               <img src ="link1" >
               <img src ="link2" >
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <h4>
      <a href= "aspPage.aspx">text</a>
   </h4>
   <div class="imgClass0">
       <p>some text</p>
    </div>
   <div class="imgClass1">
       <p>some text</p>
    </div>
   <div class="imgClass2">
       <p>some text</p>
</div>
```

Hey guys !

I have a problem. I have a div whithin I can have one or more `<img>` nodes, depends how the server generates the DOM (there can be one or many, depends on a number from the database.
There are several `<div>` elements under the `<h4>` node, the number of them is equal to the number of `<img>` elements from above.

I need help in making a javascript that makes "imgClass1" visible when I hover  `<img src ="link1" >`, and the other imgClassX, X=(1..n) invisible, and so on. I give them default visibility `display:none`, but I need imgClass0 to have default `visibility:visible.`

Best regards,
iusmar.

Comment: any code? you only pasted the html, what have you tried? a few suggestions: your div classes looks like IDs, why don't you use something like "<div id='imgClass1' class='some_class' >", that way you can hide all divs with "some_class" at once; "parent.chil.child.child" is a terrible class, "parent" is too generic, use something clearer, rethink what's the use of each div and you will get a better name for id's and classes

Comment: Initialy I wanted to match the last character of the img and and the div, where they were equal, make it visible, where not, viceversa. I don't have too much code to show, it's stupid what I wrote.

Comment: My classes have expressive names, I just named parent.child and so on to help you make an ideea about how the DOM is structured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attribute [starts with](https://www.google.com.sg/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=-D0VU4StE4f2rQenvYDYBg#q=jquery%20attribute%20starts%20with) selector along with [:eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector:

```
$('img[src^=link]').hover(function() {
    var idx = $(this).index();
    $('div[class^="imgClass"]:eq(' + idx + ')').show();
}, function() {
    var idx = $(this).index();
    $('div[class^="imgClass"]:eq(' + idx + ')').hide();
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5JgC8/)**

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
$("img[src=link1]").hover(function(){
$("div[class^='imgClass']").hide();
$(".imgClass1").show();
});
```

[fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ACTa4/)

Answer (score 0):

First, you should put a class on your images to use as a selector. You should also put the image ID as a data attribute on the tags. This will allow you to easily assign an event handler when hovering these images, and also easily extract the image ID:

```
<img src="link0" class="yourImages" data-image-id="0">
<img src="link1" class="yourImages" data-image-id="1">
<img src="link2" class="yourImages" data-image-id="2">
```

You could also apply that ID to the divs:

```
<div class="images" data-image-id="0">
    <p>some text</p>
</div>
<div class="images" data-image-id="1">
    <p>some text</p>
</div>
<div class="images" data-image-id="2">
    <p>some text</p>
</div>
```

Then you can bind a [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) handler to the `yourImages` class, get the ID from the hovered element, hide all image divs then show only the required one:

```
$('.yourImages').hover(function() {
    var imageID = $(this).data('image-id');

    $('.images').hide();
    $('.images[data-image-id="' + imageID + '"]').show();
}, function() {
    $('.images').hide();
});
```

What do you want to do when you stop hovering over any images? My example just hides them all again.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class / id just like following for the images

```
 <img class="img0" src ="link0" >
    <img class="img1" src ="link1" >
    <img class="img2" src ="link2" >
```

and try the following javascript

```
$("img").hover(function (){     
            var cls=$(this).attr("class");
            $("div[class^='imgClass']").hide();
            var visibleCls=".imgClass"+(parseInt(cls.replace("img","")));
            $(visibleCls).show();
        });
```